# Trying to define a function that creates lists from files and uses random.choices to choose an element from the weighted lists

Tags: function, random

I'm trying to define a function that will create lists from multiple text files and print a random element from one of the weighted lists. I've managed to get the function to work with random.choice for a single list.

enter code here

```
def test_rollitems():
    my_commons = open('common.txt')
    all_common_lines = my_commons.readlines()
    common = []
    for i in all_common_lines:
        common.append(i)
    y = random.choice(common)
    print(y)
```

When I tried adding a second list to the function it wouldn't work and my program just closes when the function is called.

```
enter code here
def Improved_rollitem():
    #create the lists from the files#
    my_commons = open('common.txt')
    all_common_lines= my_commons.readlines()
    common = []
    for i in all_common_lines:
        common.append(i)
    my_uncommons = open('uncommon.txt')
    all_uncommon_lines =my_uncommons.readlines()
    uncommon =[]
    for i in all_uncommon_lines:
        uncommon.apend(i)

    y = random.choices([common,uncommon], [80,20])
    print(y)
```

Can anyone offer any insight into what I'm doing wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured this out on my own! Was having issues with Geany so I installed Pycharm and was able to work through the issue. Correct code is:

```
enter code here
def Improved_rollitem():
    #create the lists from the files#
    my_commons = open('common.txt')
    all_common_lines= my_commons.readlines()
    common = []
    for i in all_common_lines:
        common.append(i)
    my_uncommons = open('uncommon.txt')
    all_uncommon_lines =my_uncommons.readlines()
    uncommon =[]
    for i in all_uncommon_lines:
       uncommon.append(i)

    y = random.choices([common,uncommon], [.8,.20])
    if y == [common]:
        for i in [common]:
            print(random.choice(i))
    if y == [uncommon]:
        for i in [uncommon]:
            print(random.choice(i))
```

If there's a better way to do something like this, it would certainly be cool to know though.